# Remove all special characters and also first character of string

Tags: postgresql

I use postgresql 11

I want to remove all special caracters and after that remove the first character of words which start with this characters `"اآٱإأ"`

this is the possibility of text :

```
 أحمد بن حنبل

آحمد بن حنبل.

إحمد  بن، حنبل

 احمد بن حنبل


 .أحمد. بن حنبل.
```

all result should be `حمد بن حنبل`

so remove all special characters and then remove the first character of words which start with this characters `"اآٱإأ"`

I find the way to remove special characters but I want in the same pattern remove also the first character of words which start with this character `اآٱإأ`

I try with this code :

```
select regexp_replace('آحمد ! بن، حنبل',  '[^\w]+',' ','g')
```

can someone help me to find the correct query

Answer (score 1):

You are already doing good! All that is missing is to remove the first character, if appropriate:

```
select regexp_replace(
          regexp_replace('آحمد ! بن، حنبل',  '[^\w]+',' ','g'),
          '^[اآٱإأ]?(.*)',
          '\1'
       );

 regexp_replace 
════════════════
 حمد بن حنبل
(1 row)
```

Note that for `\w` to work as expected, the database has to be created with an Arabic locale.